# How to determine if a string can be manipulated to be rewritten as a palindrome?

Tags: palindrome

I believe this can be achieved by counting the instances for each character in that string. Even if a single character in that string is repeated at least twice, we can declare that string as a palindrome.

For example: bbcccc can be rewritten as bccccb or ccbbcc.
edified can be rewritten as deified.

Some book mentioned we should be using hash table. I think we can just use a list and check for the character count.

Do you think the logic is correct?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think the set of all characters that have an odd frequency can be at most 1 to be able to make a palindrome. So you can't have 'aaabbb' and make a palindrome, but you can have 'aabbb'.

Comment: You don't need to use a hash table, but you could have the hash key be each character in the string and the value be the character count.  But there might be more clever ways to just track the `odd` character counts in a list.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the main idea is to count the times of each char existing in the string. And it will be true if the string has at most one char occurs odd times and all others even times.

For example:

1. `aabbcc` => `acbbca`
2. `aabcc`  => `acbca`
3. `aabbb`  => `abbba`

Answer (score 1):

No.  You don't have to use a hash map (as some of the other answers suggest).  But the efficiency of the solution will be determined by the algorithm you use.

Here is a solution that only tracks odd characters.  If we get 2 odds, we know it can't be a scrambled palindrome.  I use an array to track the odd count.  I reuse the array index 0 over and over until I find an odd.  Then I use array index 1.  If I find 2 odds, return false!

#### Solution without a hash map in javascript:

```
function isScrambledPalindrome(input) {
    // TODO: Add error handling code.
    var a = input.split("").sort();
    var char, nextChar = "";
    var charCount = [ 0 ];
    var charIdx = 0;
    for ( var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        char = a[i];
        nextChar = a[i + 1] || "";
        charCount[charIdx]++;
        if (char !== nextChar) {
            if (charCount[charIdx] % 2 === 1) {
                if (charCount.length > 1) {
                    // A scrambled palindrome can only have 1 odd char count.
                    return false;
                }
                charIdx = 1;
                charCount.push(0);
            } else if (charCount[charIdx] % 2 === 0) {
                charCount[charIdx] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

console.log("abc: " + isScrambledPalindrome("abc")); // false
console.log("aabbcd: " + isScrambledPalindrome("aabbcd")); // false
console.log("aabbb: " + isScrambledPalindrome("aabbb")); // true
console.log("a: " + isScrambledPalindrome("a")); // true
```

Using a hash map, I found a cool way to only track the odd character counts and still determine the answer.

#### Fun javascript hash map solution:

```
function isScrambledPalindrome( input ) { 
    var chars = {}; 
    input.split("").forEach(function(char) { 
    if (chars[char]) { 
        delete chars[char] 
    } else { 
        chars[char] = "odd" } 
    }); 
    return (Object.keys(chars).length <= 1); 
}

isScrambledPalindrome("aba"); // true
isScrambledPalindrome("abba"); // true
isScrambledPalindrome("abca"); // false
```

Comment: Nice solution! but the way you have used the array is just a specialised example of a hash map (your hash is a 1 to 1 or straight through mapping into the array indexes). The difference is your hash implementation has no need for collision detection etc, because you only store the odd/even info rather than the letters themselves. Not sure how javascript works with initialisation, but you could be merely trading space (initialising an array the size of all possible values of char) vs using a non 1 to 1 hash to keep the size small.

Comment: Hi @m2o2r2g2.  You're right.  It's a hash map implementation.  I will make that more explicit in my comments.  I thought of another implementation with a sorted array which I will also add.

Answer (score 1):

My code check if can it is palindrome or can be manipulated to Palindrome

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>

    //Tested on windows 64 bit arhc by using cygwin64 and GCC

    bool isPalindrome (char *text);

    int main()
    {
       char text[100]; // it could be N with defining N

       bool isPal,isPosPal = false;
       printf("Give me a string to test if it is Anagram of Palindrome\n");
       gets(text);
     
       isPal = isPalindrome(text);
       isPosPal = isAnagramOfPalindrome(text);
       if(isPal == false)
        {
            printf("Not a palindrome.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Palindrome.\n");
        }
       if(isPosPal == false)
        {
            printf("Not Anagram of Palindrome\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Anagram of Palindrome\n");
        }
     
       return 0;
    }


    bool isPalindrome (char *text) {
       int begin, middle, end, length = 0;

       length = getLength(text);
       end = length - 1;
       middle = length/2;
     
       for (begin = 0; begin < middle; begin++)
       {
          if (text[begin] != text[end])
          {
               return false;        
          }
          end--;
       }
       if (begin == middle)
          return true;
    }

    int getLength (char *text) { 
       int length = 0;
       while (text[length] != '\0')
       length++;
       printf("length: %d\n",length);
       return length;
    }

    int isAnagramOfPalindrome (char *text) { 

        int length = getLength(text);
        int i = 0,j=0;
        bool arr[26] = {false};
        int counter = 0;
        //char string[100]="neveroddoreven";
        int a;
        

        
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            a = text[i];
            a = a-97;

            if(arr[a])
            {
                arr[a] = false;
            }
            else
            {
                arr[a] = true;
            }
        }
        
        for(j = 0; j < 27 ; j++)
        {
            if (arr[a] == true)
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        
        printf("counter: %d\n",counter);
        if(counter > 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(counter == 1)
        {
            if(length % 2 == 0)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
        else if(counter == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Any string can be palindrome only if at most one character occur odd no. of times and all other characters must occur even number of times.
The following program can be used to check whether a palindrome can be string or not.

```
vector<int> vec(256,0); //Vector for all ASCII characters present.
for(int i=0;i<s.length();++i)
{
    vec[s[i]-'a']++;
}
int odd_count=0,flag=0;
for(int i=0;i<vec.size();++i)
{
    if(vec[i]%2!=0)
        odd_count++;
    if(odd_count>1)
    {
        flag=1;
        cout<<"Can't be palindrome"<<endl;
        break;  
    }
}
if(flag==0)
    cout<<"Yes can be palindrome"<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

as others have posted, the idea is to have each character occur an even number of times for an even length string, and one character an odd number of times for an odd length string.

The reason the books suggest using a hash table is due to execution time. It is an O(1) operation to insert into / retrieve from a hash map. Yes a list can be used but the execution time will be slightly slower as the sorting of the list will be O(N log N) time.

Pseudo code for a list implementation would be:

```
sortedList = unsortedList.sort;

bool oddCharFound = false;

//if language does not permit nullable char then initialise 
//current char to first element, initialise count to 1 and loop from i=1
currentChar = null;
currentCharCount = 0;
for (int i=0; i <= sortedList.Length; i++) //start from first element go one past end of list
{
    if(i == sortedList.Length 
        || sortedList[i] != currentChar)
    {
        if(currentCharCount % 2 = 1)
        {
            //check if breaks rule
            if((sortedList.Length % 2 = 1 && oddCharFound)
                || oddCharFound)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                oddCharFound = true;
            }
        }
        if(i!= sortedList.Length)
        {
            currentCharCount = 1;
            currentChar = sortedList[i];
        }

    }
    else
    {
        currentCharCount++;
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: You don't have to sort anything as you just have to determine if it is possible. Also, he could use a simple array since the number of characters is finite and rather small; the code would be simpler.

Comment: @Marichyasana Yes he can use an array, but If he doesn't sort the array, he will have to search the array each time he processes a character to determine a count which will make it just as slow and more complex.

Comment: That is why the "books" suggest to use a hash map. It is the best solution. I merely provided the solution the poster asked for.

Comment: Hi @m2o2r2g2.  I ported your code to javascript (my fav) and ran a few tests.  This is a good solution and probably faster than my array solution, but it fails for input "abc";

Comment: @Jess Sorry about that, pitfall of only writing pseudo code and not running. There is the option of initialising the char and count with the first entry (for languages with non nullable char), or initialising with null and 0 and running loop from first entry. Unfortunately I did the variables assuming second method and the loop assuming first. Will fix it now.

Comment: @m2o2r2g2 Assume unicode is not being used and each char is one byte. Then use the value of the char as an index into the array and  increment the corresponding array element for each char in the input. After processing the input string just check the array. No sorting necessary. This should be just as fast or faster than a hash.

Comment: @Marichyasana Your solution is basically the same algorithmic approach as what Jess has done. You are still using an external hashing structure, just with 1 to 1 hash function (ie structure storing count objects has an index for each possible value of the problem space). So you have not avoided using an external hashing function, you have simply traded space (a 256 length array as opposed to an array closer in size to distinct set of values in list) for the fastest possible hash function of a direct mapping. As I mentioned to Jess I think that is better but poster asked to avoid hash structure

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using an array; no sort needed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a[256] = { 0 };
    unsigned char i[] = {"aaBcBccc"};
    unsigned char *p = &i[0];
    int c = 0;
    int j;
    int flag = 0;
    while (*p != 0)
    {
        a[*p]++;
        p++;
    }
    for(j=0; j<256; j++)
    {
        if(a[j] & 1)
        {
            c++;
            if(c > 1)
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag)
        printf("Nope\n");
    else
        printf("yup\n");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Nice C programming.  I like how you programmed in `C` and one of your lines is `c++;`   :D

Comment: This is a very cool implementation and I like how you use the `&` operator.  You are using an array, but you are using the array more like a hash table.  (Instead of the hash key being a char/string you have a index being the numerical value of the char)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all input characters are lower case letters.

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

char *str;
char arr[27];
int j;
int a;
j = 0;
printf("Enter the string : ");
scanf("%s", str);
while (*str != '\0'){
    a = *str;
    a = a%27;

    if(arr[a] == *str){
        arr[a]=0;
        j--;
    }else{
        arr[a] = *str;
        j++;
    }
    *str++;
}
if(j==0 || j== -1 || j==1){
    printf ("\nThe string can be a palindrome\n");

}
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how this code works? You could start by giving a better name to this `j` variable.

Comment: For a string to be palindrome, each letter must have a corresponding pair and one letter can have no pair. The variable 'j' when 0 indicates even number of letters in the string and all are paired. variable 'j' when 1 or -1 indicates odd number of letters in the string with all letters paired except one.  For eg string "aadssaa" has pairs (a,a)(s,s)(a,a) and individual letter (d). This algorithm would say this string can be a palindrome.  Makes sense ?

Answer (score 0):

C#:

```
bool ok = s.GroupBy(c => c).Select(g => g.Count()).Where(c => c == 1).Count() < 2;
```

This solution, however, *does* use hashing.